# Spark-Submit Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I am trying to `spark-submit` an application in Scala cluster mode.It was working fine in PySpark but while trying to run with Scala the above error is popping up. If I have to add SBT and Maven dependencies can you elaborate the procedure(I am not able to find in Google)

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object MyFirst {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // create Spark context with Spark configuration
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"))

    // get threshold
    val threshold = args(1).toInt

    // read in text file and split each document into words
    val tokenized = sc.textFile(args(0)).flatMap(_.split(" "))

    // count the occurrence of each word
    val wordCounts = tokenized.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

    // filter out words with fewer than threshold occurrences
    val filtered = wordCounts.filter(_._2 >= threshold)

    // count characters
    val charCounts = filtered.flatMap(_._1.toCharArray).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

    System.out.println(charCounts.collect().mkString(", "))
  }
}
```

Here is my Build.sbt

```
name := "MyFirst"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
```

*My Spark Submit was*: spark-submit MyFirst --class MyFirst /home/ram/Downloads/sbt/src/target/scala-2.10/MyFirst_2.10-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: pls share your build.sbt and code

Comment: Please share your spark-submit arguments

Comment: You need to set main class path with package for example --class com.example.MyFirst

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie to spark.Do you mean I have to define a package name at the start of the program or during spark submit?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before.

Try defining a package for your class, something like this:

```
package com.testing

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object MyFirst {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // create Spark context with Spark configuration
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"))
    // more code ...
  }
}
```

And then use:

```
spark-submit MyFirst --class com.testing.MyFirst /home/ram/Downloads/sbt/src/target/scala-2.10/MyFirst_2.10-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Also make sure you have created the [MANIFEST.MF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) file.

Here's a brief example of what would it look like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.testing.MyFirst
```